# Installing package in R Console in IBM Bluemix

Tags: r, ibm-cloud, install.packages, dashdb

I am not able to install packages in R console in dashDB from IBM Bluemix. I am executing the below line:

```
install.packages('tm')
```

I am getting this error:

```
Installing package into ‘/usr/lib64/R/library’ (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages("tm") :
    'lib = "/usr/lib64/R/library"' is not writable
    Error in install.packages("tm") : unable to install packages
    Execution halted
    mv: cannot stat `/mnt/blumeta0/home/<userID>//<...>/<...>/output/*': No such file or directory
```

I have also tried giving the library parameters like this:

```
install.packages('tm', lib='/mnt/blumeta0/home/<userID>/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.2/lib')
```

I get this error:

```
Warning in install.packages("tm", lib = "/mnt/blumeta0/home/<userID>/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.2/lib/"):  
'lib = "/mnt/blumeta0/home/<userID>/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.2/lib/"' is not writable.
Execution halted
mv: cannot stat `/mnt/blumeta0/home/dash107933//.3hwv1S2IEeq813rI935Gurz/1467874427867/output/*': No such file or directory
```

What could be the issue here? Do I have to do any other configuration changes before I try to install the packages? I have also tried to use `.libPaths()` function to set the library to above mentioned path. 
The packages are getting installed properly in RStudio interface though.
Could you please help? Thanks!

PS: The keyinfo and UserIDs are removed in above statements.

Comment: Do you have write and execute rights on that machine?

Comment: No. I don't think so. It's in IBM Bluemix cloud so not sure how to get write and execute rights to that. But since I am able to install the packages from RStudio interface, I feel this may not be the issue. Please correct if I am wrong.

Comment: try to refer to the repository, e.g. install.packages('tm',repos="http://cran.rstudio.com/")

Answer (score 0):

I have installed packages using the 'Install Packages' menu item from the Tools Menu. Did you try that ?

[See this picture for the menu location. Bluemix R Studio Web Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xStuM.png)

Comment: Thanks Kiran. This worked! I installed all packages from the RStudio menu rather than giving it in the script and this installed the libraries properly which are available in R Console as well. Thanks a lot for pointing out this option.